# Angular 4.x router cancels and reroutes without reason

Tags: angular, angular-routing

My Angular app behaves really strangely: it seems to work at first but after I visit one lazy loaded module the router decides to change my navigation.

I have a group view in the user frontend and admin settings; when I load the app I can visit group view just fine in the user part, but after I've visited the admin settings once, almost every group selection in the user section brings me to the admin settings. Investigating this I enabled router tracing, and it seems like the router resolves the correct route, cancels it, then navigates to the wrong one.

I was unable to post the text of the router log in a good format so here is a screenshot of it:

[image: console screenshot]

The later failure is because I removed the wrong target route temporarily.
This is the source code of basically the whole thing https://gitlab.com/pikandpeople/next
Also here is my `ng version` output:

```
@angular/cli: 1.3.0-rc.3
node: 7.7.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.3.2
@angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.8
@angular/common: 4.3.2
@angular/compiler: 4.3.2
@angular/core: 4.3.2
@angular/flex-layout: 2.0.0-rc.1
@angular/forms: 4.3.2
@angular/http: 4.3.2
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.8
@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.2
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.2
@angular/router: 4.3.2
@angular/service-worker: 1.0.0-beta.16
@angular/cli: 1.3.0-rc.3
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.2
@angular/language-service: 4.3.2
```

I have really no clue why this is happening and would be glad of input.

Comment: Can you post your router code and the base.component.ts file?

Comment: If the routes are clean. Can you also mention what you are doing in your constructor or the ngOnInit code? There is an issue in the route, constructor or the ngOnInit. Any NavigationStart event being captured by you?

Comment: I put up the code on gitlab and added the link